# Is this function computable?

Tags: computability

Given a function like:

f(x) = x=y then 1 else 0

The number y is a natural number, other than that is unknown

I had two approaches in mind:

- The function is computable since an algorithm exists, that can compare two numbers, and tell whether they are equal return 1, otherwise 0.
- The function is not computable, since we would need to know the number y to write an algorithm that compares the numbers.

Can someone give me a hint into the right direction?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: "we would need to know the number": which one ?

Comment: If $y$ is unknown but natural, then the function $f$ tells if $x$ is natural. But calculability deals with natural numbers, so the function value is always $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common definition of a computable function $f(x) : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{N}$ is as follows:

> There exists a Turing machine that given $x\in \mathcal{X}$ on its initial tape will produce $f(x)$ after a finite amount of steps.

Note that it only requires such a Turing machine to *exist*.

Now for your question, we can produce an infinite set of Turing machines by mapping each natural number $y$ to a Turing machine that tests if its input $x$ equals $y$. Each of these Turing machines obviously exists. Since your function $f$ is equivalent to one of these Turing machines, it must be computable.